# Finding string literals in my code

Tags: php, regex

At my company we recently noticed that one developer was not using language files but putting text directly in the code.

My idea was to search for words between quotes that have atleast 1 or more whitespace in them. But I got kinda stuck with

```
("|')(\w|\s{1,})*('|")
```

this does match text but does not require that it has atleast 1 word and atleast 1 whitespace (so it matches about anything between quotes). Can anyone help me out?

The language I want to use for this is PHP (or I could do a notepad++ search)

Comment: Added the language to the question

Comment: What's inside the quotes of interest? Anything besides words and spaces? Do they look like `"foo bar baz"`? Are escapes allowed? What language is the code that the developer in question was using (the code you are searching)?

Comment: quotes will be text, which will be displayed on web applications so it can be "foo bar bar" but also something like 'Warning: you didn\'t fill in all the required fields!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match single or double quoted strings (without escapes) that contain a "word" and a space you could use:

```
"(?=[^"\n]*\w)(?=[^"\n]*\s)[^"\n]+"|'(?=[^'\n]*\w)(?=[^'\n]*\s)[^'\n]+'
```

In PHP it would look like:

```
preg_match_all("/\"(?=[^\"\n]*\\w)(?=[^\"\n]*\\s)[^\"\n]+\"|'(?=[^'\n]*\\w)(?=[^'\n]*\\s)[^'\n]+'/", $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! To bad I can't read it all yet need to take some time to study regex soon. Only problem now is that it also takes all the words between literals. Could a search for EOL fix this?

Comment: +1, hoping the strings can't contain escapes. If they could, a regex would become quite messy. I've retracted my solution because I found more and more edge cases where it would fail...

Comment: @Rob, "it also takes all the words between literals", what do you mean? Can you give some examples? You might also want to change all those `[^"]` and `[^']` to `[^"\n]` and `[^'\n]` if the strings do not span multiple lines. @Tim, thanks. And you are right, if there were escapes it would probably be better to write it in another way, more like yours.

Comment: If I have 2 strings, one @ line 2 and the other at line 50 then the regex would return the 48 lines code between those strings aswell. The \n fixed this. I know that the solution isn't 100% but will get most of it, the rest we will have to look for manually.

Comment: @Rob, do quotes span multiple lines? Can you have several quotes per line? How exactly is it "not 100%"? Feel free to give some examples.

Comment: I don't think the literals will span multiple lines, but since I didn't write the code I can't be 100% sure. Also this doesn't account for escaped quotes which might've been used. 

Altho my solution is to look for strings that seem 'unfinished' as in half sentences and look them up manually which should be fine (expecting that line breaks and escapes are rare).